# fullPage.js, scrollDelay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

ScrollDelay will not work using the following code placed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

http://oskarvertetics.kaggteknik.se/portfolio/test2/

```
var scrollDelay = 500;
```

Also, can not seem to figure out what is wrong with the navigation on the right side and in the slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ScrollDelay will not work using the following code placed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

`scrollDelay` stop being used in fullPage.js [since version 2.5.7](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/commit/fafa7e0fc1157666618504efce0b962cd2b7738a) as a new technique to prevent double sliding was developed. 
 In fact, you won't find any reference to it neither in the code nor in the docs.

> Also, can not seem to figure out what is wrong with the navigation on the right side and in the slides.

Your are initializing the plugin multiple times...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                verticalCentered: false

            });
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['', '#F3F5F1', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke'],
                anchors: ['homepage', 'about', 'works', 'contact'],
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 1000
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! It solved both of my issues, removing the double initialization.